# Is proof of fund not required if you have arranged employment in Canada?

Tags: immigration, canada, employment, skilled-migration

I read [here](http://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/arrival-proof-of-funds-vs-arranged-employment-t27178.0.html) that previously one either needed proof of funds or arranged employment. However, when I took the online evaluation of whether I can move to Canada without funds but with arranged employment, they declined my application. Whats the requirement?

Answer (score 2):

The requirement is

> "Unless you are currently authorized to work in Canada **and** have a
>   valid job offer from an employer in Canada,
>
> **or**
>
> you have been invited to apply under the Canadian Experience Class"

Either way you've lived in Canada before. Having a job offer gives you more points, but doesn't remove the funds requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I came across this content on Canadian Immigration's [website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/funds.asp). Here is what it says,
You do not have to show that you have these funds if:

- you have a valid offer of arranged employment in Canada AND
- you are currently working or authorized to work in Canada.